# Most efficient method for radix conversion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a list of numbers in radix $10$. My objective is to concatenate these numbers together to form one single number, and then convert it to radix $20$.

Unfortunately, the list is pretty extensive. The concatenated number is over $1$ million digits long, so converting it to radix $20$ afterwards is very inefficient. I was wondering if it is possible to obtain the same resulting radix $20$ result by first converting each number in the list to radix $20$ and performing a separate concatenation? Or is there another way to obtain my desired result?